# Assembler get value of pointer

Tags: assembly, x86, att

At the moment I play a bit with assembler but I have one question to pointers. In my assembler program I have a String which I put in the registers EAX and I want to get the third character from the string. This works great with this code:

```
movl  $3, %esi

movl  $.STR1, %eax
movl  (%esi, %eax), %ecx
```

My problem is that I get an address to the chacrter with this command and not the ASCII value of the character. How can I access the value of the referenced pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks about right, except characters are 1 byte each, so you should either `movb (%esi, %eax), %cl` or `movzbl (%esi, %eax), %ecx`. Note you didn't get the address, you got the first 4 characters from your string packed into `%ecx`. Of course for constants you can directly do `movb .STR1+3, %cl`.